# Using pathfinder the proper way in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to use pathfinder the right way in Illustrator?

I want to subtract the black line from my image bellow so I can extract transparent png. Now I just added a red circle with a white stroke above it to get the look I need.

Its displayed correctly on white bg, but when I want to export it as transparent it wont go as it will show the white stroke...

How to achieve this? THANKS!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step-by-step instruction (active layer = Layer 1):

1. Draw a rounded rectangle on Layer 1. Name = Frame, Stroke = Black, Fill = None
2. Create Layer below Layer 1. Name = Bg
3. Draw a rectangle on Bg around Frame. Name = BgRect, Stroke = None, Fill = Yellow
4. Lock Bg
5. Draw a circle on Layer 1 above Frame. Name = OuterCircle, Stroke = None, Fill = Black
6. Draw a circle on Layer 1 above OuterCircle with the same center as OuterCircle (use Smart Guides).  Name = InnerCircle, Stroke = None, Fill = Red
7. Ensure your drawing is as shown below:[image]
8. Select Frame.  Object -> Path -> Outline Stroke.  Ensure Frame name changes to Compound Path
9. Select Compound Path and OuterCircle. Group.
10. Select Group.  Effect -> Pathfinder -> Subtract
11. Enjoy.[image]